# "To ride a bicycle" vs. "ride a bicycle"

Tags: verbs, nouns

I want to describe my hobbies and would like to say that I like bicycles.

> 1. ride as noun: I like **ride** a bicycle
> 2. ride as verb: I like to **ride** a bicycle

Which variant is right?

Comment: You must include *to* in your version, or it will be ungrammatical. But it will still sound a bit odd if you give this as a "hobby". It's much better to say *I like cycling*.

Comment: Obligatory study material courtesy of [Queen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt0V0_1MS0Q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use *ride* as a noun

   > I like bicycle rides.
2. If you use *ride* as a verb

   > I like riding bicycle.

"I like to ride a bicycle" means the same as "I want to ride a bicycle", so you shouldn't use this variant in your context.

Comment: *I like bicycle ride* sounds wrong.  *I like a/the bicycle ride* or *I like bicycle rides* would be better.

Comment: I thought it would be suitable, but since I'm a nonnative speaker of English, I accept your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When using the form with ride as a noun, we say *"I like **to ride**"*.

When using ride as a verb, we say *"I like **riding**"*.

But it doesn't sound right to say *"I like to ride **a** bicycle"* with the indefinite article "a". Instead we say:

*"I like to ride bicycles"*, or *"I like to ride my bicycle"*.

Or just avoid it altogether and say: *I enjoy cycling*!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the two presented, only the latter variant is correct, that is:

> I like to ride a bicycle.

BUT, an even better variant would be:

> I like riding a bicycle.

Comment: Both of these sound wrong because of the indefinite article, as Andrew Vit explains in his answer.